# Performance when the Backend and Frontend database don't same

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Hi experts I want to know in which scenario I have more Performance(Time to run queries):

1. If the Backend is MS SQL Server and Fontend MS Access
2. If both Backend and Frontend are Same on MS Access
3. If both Backend and Frontend are same and on MS Sql server

and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the instance of MS SQL is running on a database server rather than a stand-alone PC then this should provide superior query performance against Access. Access is limited by the processing power the the machine from which you are accessing it as due to been a file based system it has no processing power of it's own and everything must be run locally.

In terms of the front-end, it really depends on what other tasks you are looking to carry out, using an Access front-end over and MS SQL back-end is perfectly acceptable as you can still load any query processing on the server side and thus not decrease performance.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server is always faster than Access (has a better query optimizer too, amongst all other things), so just axe the Access completely...